# When to capitalize job titles?

Tags: grammar, capitalization, ielts

I'm a transcriptionist and also studying for my IELTS exam. I would like to know when is it correct to capitalize job titles such as receptionist, office assistant, general manager, veterinary assistant, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if the job title is really a title (e.g., President or Vice President), and not a job description (e.g., teacher or janitor), you can capitalize it, but only if it comes **before** the name of the person. In all other instances, it's best to lowercase titles.

For the examples you listed in your question, those titles should be lowercased.

There's a great Grammar Girl article on this topic: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-should-you-capitalize-words?page=1

Hope this helps!